# Access remote computers on cross domain using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, remote-access, powershell-remoting

I need to copy files from local machine to remote computer, but both are on different domain. I tried to connect it using powershell, but the anti virus is blocking my connection.

I cannot disable the antivirus in the remote computer. Can anyone please tell if there is a way to do this without disabling the antivirus.

Answer (score 2):

Do you try the net use command :

```
Net use o: \\Computer\share /user:domainName\remoteuser
```

Or the same using PowerShell

```
New-PSDrive -Name NDrive -PSProvider filesystem  -Root \\Computer\share  -Credential (get-credential)
```

Then you can copy to the new drive `o:` or in PowerShell `NDrive:`